# Setup Enviornment for building Framework Application & System Services in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I just want to know how to setup enviornment for developing framework Applications & Services in Android, for developing in eclipse. Currently I am using only a Text Editor. Can Anyone let me know that how to setup enviornment in eclipse. So that I can import all the internal apies.

Thanks,

Yuvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html
Here are instructions for setting up eclipse for the android source, including system frameworks and apps.

Answer (score 0):

Please watch following video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqGYWMFrE6k

Steps

1. Install JDK
2. Install Eclipse
3. Download & Extract Android SDK
4. Install ADT Plugin in Eclipse

Thank You

Comment: Its not what I want. try this in any of your class : `IBinder wmbinder = ServiceManager.getService( "window" );`